# How to read content of an iOS app from another app?

Tags: ios

I am stuck somewhere. My client wants me to develop an application that has a dedicated icon over other applications as well. For example – If I have an ecommerce application opened in my iPhone, there should be an icon over that application through which I can take screenshot and add the image to my application. I know this is possible in android, but is it possible in iOS as well, if yes then how?? Also refer the image attached for more clarification.
[image]

Comment: I did't think so it's  possible ..... in IOS @Adam Nluks.  My suggestion check any screen Recorder Samples, it will give u some knowledge

Comment: Thanks Naveen for your comment.. Can you please suggest any way through which it can be achieved, like any redirect or something.

Comment: This is not possible on iOS for non jailbroke devices. You app is running in its own sandbox and can not access data outside of this sandbox. This also includes adding any UI elements on screen outside of your apps own `UIWindow`

Comment: You can add a button with functionality only if you are the developer of the app. Then it's possible to make a screenshot and send it to another app (an app that is able to handle images). Adding functionality to other apps isn't possible for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**Share data between two applications**

Historically, the iPhone has tried to prevent data sharing between apps. The idea was that if you couldn't get at another app's data, you couldn't do anything bad to that app.

In recent releases of IOS, they've loosened that up a bit. For example, the iOS programming guide now has a section on passing data between apps by having one app claim a certain URL prefix, and then having other apps reference that URL. So, perhaps you set your event app to answer "event://" URLs the same way that a webserver answers for "http://" URLs.

Have a peek under "Implementing Custom URL Schemes".

Comment: As I understand the question, the ecomerce app isn't developed by him or his client. Therefore this solution wan't help him.